# How to use ChannelInterceptor to stop the execution flow in the Spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

There is Spring integration flow. This has to be stopped manually by the user while being run and need to use ChannelInterceptor to stop the execution. This is xml based configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the flow there is just enough to call `stop()` on the endpoint which is a beginning for the flow. Autowire an `AbstractEndpoint` for the specific `id` and call its `stop()`. It really doesn't matter if you are going to do that in the `ChannelInterceptor` or some other service.

There is also a common patterns called `Control Bus`, where one of the commands to send could be the mentioned `stop()` operation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#control-bus